# HTTP authentication fails when password is into URL, but succeeded using interactive password prompt - why?

Tags: authentication, passwords, credentials

I'm trying to access git via HTTP from CI pipeline using access token as a password (using SSH is not an option). If build credentials into URL, it doesn't work:

```
$ git clone http://username:pass-_word123@git.host/my/repo.git

Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://git.host/my/repo.git/'
```

But if enter credentials in interactive mode - it works fine:

```
$ git clone http://git.host/my/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
Username for 'https://git.host:443': username
Password for 'https://username@git.host:443': pass-_word123

Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 72, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (72/72), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (53/53), done.
remote: Total 72 (delta 21), reused 60 (delta 17), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (72/72), 7.90 KiB | 7.90 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (21/21), done.
```

Why is it so? And how to fix that?

My password consists only of Latin characters, numbers and symbols "-" and "_" as shown in example above, so it is not special characters-related problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I'm trying to git clone from `http://git.host/...` , but server `git.host` is set up to answer only via HTTPS, not HTTP.

If request `http://git.host/my/repo.git` from browser (or curl), I can see `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` response from the server, and then browser (or curl) do second request to `httpS://git.host/...` - but if deal with this server from CLI `git` client, it cannot properly follow HTTP 301 response for some unknown reasons.

This problem manifests exactly in the way described in the question: credentials could be successfully passed to the server only in interactive mode, but not when they are integrated into request URL.

Solution to this problem is quite simple: use `httpS://git.host/...` instead of `http://git.host/...` in `git clone` CLI command, so it properly uses the credentials passed through command-line into URL:

```
### Request with HTTP - this does not works:
$ git clone http://username:pass-_word123@git.host/my/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://git.host/my/repo.git/'

### Request with HTTPS - this works fine:
$ git clone httpS://username:pass-_word123@git.host/my/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 370, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (99/99), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
remote: Total 370 (delta 28), reused 87 (delta 23), pack-reused 271
Receiving objects: 100% (370/370), 46.43 KiB | 779.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (94/94), done.
```